Build error on Expo EAS - Caused by expo-camera
I've been looking for someone to help me with this issue for a while now. I have a React-native app built using expo and I'm using expo-camera to take pictures for my app. For some reason, I'm having an issue when building the app using EAS cli. This is the error that causes the failure:

w: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-camera/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/camera/tasks/ResolveTakenPicture.kt:146:32 Type mismatch: inferred type is String? But String was expected

So, I noticed that it seems to be related when I take the picture, it seems that the return value is not a String, which is confusing because I'm setting that correctly, anyway, this is how I'm calling the CameraView component inside of my app, in here I set some props coming from a state.
   <CameraView
      style={styles.camera}
      zoom={cameraProps.zoom}
      facing={cameraProps.facing}
      flash={cameraProps.flash}
      animateShutter={cameraProps.animateShutter}
      enableTorch={cameraProps.enableTorch}
      ref={cameraRef}            
    />

This is the function that is called when the picture is taken:
  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      try {
        console.log('Taking a picture...');
        console.log(cameraRef.current);
        const picture = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
        console.log(picture);
        setImage(picture.uri || "");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error while taking the picture : ', err);
      }
    }
  }

Can anyone help me to fix this? No documentation could help me with that.
